# Error: "Duplicate collection entry" in Windows Server 2022 config file

Tags: tomcat, windows-server

I have TomCat 10 installed on Windows Server 2022. It generates twice an IsApiFilters in the config file

```
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <isapiFilters>
      <filter name="tomcat" path="C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 10.1\isapi\isapi_redirect.dll" preCondition="bitness32" />
    </isapiFilters>type here
```

and

```
  <location path="Default Web Site">
    <system.webServer>
      <isapiFilters>
        <filter name="tomcat" path="C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 10.1\isapi\isapi_redirect.dll" preCondition="bitness32" />
      </isapiFilters>
```

It gives this error: Cannot add duplicate collection entry of type 'filter' with unique key attribute 'name' set to 'tomcat'.

How can I prevent this duplicate generation?

I commented the first one out. But i am not sure of the consequences.